# How to change while loop expression when running

Tags: java, android, while-loop

I am developing a program that runs a while loop in one of its local functions named `Record()`. When a button named X is pressed, a variable condition gets true and record function runs. I want when another button Y is pressed the condition be changed and therefore while loop stop. 
The problem is: when while loop starts it doesn't listen to click of button Y. What should i do. to stop while loop by changing its condition from some other function.
Sample code is like below:

```
// clicking Button Y
private View.OnClickListener XonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {            
            condition = true;               
            record();               
    }
}

// clicking Button Y
private View.OnClickListener YonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {            
            condition = false;          
    }
} 

// Record function
private void Record(){
    while (condition){          
            // do something
    } 
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's wrong without *actual* code (since you don't know what the bug is, you're probably leaving out the bit that is causing the problem). However, my initial guess is that `condition` is not declared `volatile`.

Comment: How are you accessing the Record method?

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your question that you're running that `while` loop in the UI thread (also known as the main thread). This thread isn't supposed to do any actual work except driving the UI (e.g. drawing images) and being driven by the UI (e.g. processing button click events). Any other job should go to other threads. So if you're running the while loop in your UI thread, it's unavailable to listen to button click events.

You can find a general explanation of this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html), and there are a lot of mechanisms that can help you do your `Record()` work asynchronously, such as `AsyncTask` for which you can find a nice tutorial [here](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.Us0SV_iLelM). My personal favorite is the `HandlerThread`, simply because it's very flexible and easily expandable. You will need to [understand](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) the `Looper` and `Message` concepts as well though to get the most out of it.